# How to set a maximum width of 100% within nested flexboxes?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm almost sure this question has already been asked and solved but despite a thorough research I wasn't able to find any answer solving my specific case, hence my actual question.

I would like the table contained within the `.card` div to be overflowed but despite multiple attempts I didn't find a way for my flex boxes to take into account the `max-width: 100%` CSS property attached to this `.card` div (that should normally limit its width to 100% related on its parent width). It's like the table width take precedence over all the parent widths.

Here is a reproducible version of my last failed attempt:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
 
.main {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.table {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p>.menu</p>
 </div>

<div class="main">
  <p>.main</p>
  
  <div class="card">
    <p>.card</p>
    
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>dolor</td><td>sit</td><td>amet</td><td>consectetur</td><td>adipiscing</td><td>elit</td><td>sed</td><td>do</td><td>tempor</td><td>incididunt</td><td>ut</td><td>labore</td><td>et</td><td>dolore</td><td>magna</td><td>aliqua</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: min-width:0 on .main

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work actually (unless I'm doing something wrong...), even with an added width and/or a max-width of 100% on the table.

Comment: you said *I would like the table contained within the .card div to be overflowed* and you was talking about .card. Adding min-width:0 to main will fix the width related to card and you table will logically overflow

Comment: if you want a scrollbar, add overflow:auto to card not table

Comment: Indeed that was my issue! Thank you very much again!